# Angularjs controller's scope data dependant on async http data inside the service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a single page application with 2 tabs each tab having its own controller.
Some of view labels on each tab is actually returned from the server. So I kept the async http return data in a service. 
But the problem is even before the data is returned from service, the data-binding of controller is completed and I get an undefined label on the page.

**Here is my HTML COde**

```
<!-- Sample Html Code-->
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="tablCtrl">{{page1.label}}</div>
<div ng-controller="tab2Ctrl">{{page2.label}}</div>
</body>
```

**This is my Angular app.js Code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.service('serverData',['$http',function($http){
    this.labels = {};
    $http.post('/server/labels',{}).then(function(resp){
        this.labels = resp.data.labels
    },function(err){
        console.log("Error in service while fetching data")
    })
}])

myApp.controller('tab1Ctrl',['$scope','serverData',function($scope,serverData){
$scope.page1 = serverData.labels;
//page1 object has the label1 key with some value
```

}])

```
myApp.controller('tab2Ctrl',['$scope','serverData',function($scope,serverData){
$scope.page2 = serverData.labels;
//page1 object has the label1 key with some value
```

}])

Now the problem is that before the service returns its data while instantiation, the controller doesn't wait but completes its execution and hence it has the **empty** serverData.labels object.

I have read about angular $compile service, but I'm not sure if I can use it in my controller and how. Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no data because the data call is asynchronous but you tread it as something synchronous, if you change your code like this it should work:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('serverData',['$http',function($http){

    this.getLabels = $http.post('/server/labels',{}).then(function(resp){
        return resp.data.labels;
    },function(err){
        console.log("Error in service while fetching data")
    })
}]);

myApp.controller('tab1Ctrl',['$scope','serverData',function($scope,serverData){
    serverData.getLabels()
        .then(function(labels) {
            $scope.page1 = labels;
        });
}]);

myApp.controller('tab2Ctrl',['$scope','serverData',function($scope,serverData){
    serverData.getLabels()
        .then(function(labels) {
            $scope.page2 = labels;
        });
}]);
```

More info about `$q` and `promises` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: If I understand correctly, serverData.getLabels() return a promise.
I am remote and I haven't executed this. But I want confirm one thing. 
Sine the service is singleton, is the http post going to happen once in its first instantiation or will it be invoked separately for each controller? I have 7other controllers as part of single page app. So, do I need to use the same coding pattern. Is this a right design pattern while coding angular JS?

Answer (score 0):

In your `serverData` service `this.labels = {};` and in `$http.post` `this.labels = resp.data.labels` did not refer same object. You can assing `this` in a variable and use that variable to assign response lebel.

like: `var vm = this;`

In service:

```
myApp.service('serverData',['$http',function($http){
    var vm = this;
    vm.labels = {};
    $http.post('/server/labels',{}).then(function(resp){
        //vm.labels = resp.data.labels
        angular.extend(vm.labels, resp.data.labels);
    },function(err){
        console.log("Error in service while fetching data")
    })
}]);
```

and in Controller:

```
myApp.controller('tab1Ctrl' ['$scope','serverData',function($scope,serverData){
     $scope.page1 = serverData.labels;
}]);
```

Comment: still won't work unless `vm.labels` is an object and that object never gets replaced....just extended. ... `vm.labels={}` ...  in callback `angular.extend(vm.labels, resp.data.labels)`

Comment: still overwriting the object reference. Can't reassign `vm.labels` after controller has it referenced to original object. Service and controller would then be referencing 2 different objects

Comment: now used `angular.extend(vm.labels, resp.data.labels);`

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$q` as a dependency in your service, and write a function instead :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.service('serverData',['$http','$q',function($http,$q){

    this.getLabels = function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.post('/server/labels',{}).then(function(resp){
         var labels = resp.data.labels
         deferred.resolve(labels);
       },function(err){
          deferred.reject(err);
        console.log("Error in service while fetching data")
       })
      return deferred.promise;
    };


}])

    myApp.controller('tab1Ctrl',['$scope','serverData',function($scope,serverData){
       serverData.getLabels().then(
         function(labels){
           $scope.page1 = labels;
         },
         function(err){
           console.log('err',err);
         });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, but do you want to include all the complexity pertaining to response on controller. Best way is to make your controller as thin as possible. For this case though we are directly returning the response, but in same cases you want to do some pre-processing and then apply the processed data on model. Hence, controller should just get the data what needs to be applied on model. Hence, used $q.

Comment: Keeping controller thin will keep your code maintainable and when you change any functionality you just modify the service/factory and hence you end up having fewer bugs as controller code is stills same. Basically, makes the code modular which is imperative for faster debugging.